# WP7 dynamic controls

Tags: dynamic, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to generate dynamic WP7 controls in code behind (.cs)  using  .xaml template (like inflating in Android) ,
 or should I generate it all manually? For example I need dynamic tabs (PivotItems)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pete Brown recently demonstrated how to dynamically generate xaml here if you'd like to look into that route.

[Dynamically Generating Controls in WPF and Silverlight](http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/08/dynamically-generating-controls-in-wpf-and-silverlight)

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem using UserControls but this looks realy interesting

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so - but definitely not recommended.

I am not sure why you would want to have more than three pivot items in any application anyway. Simply have three and reuse them as they wrap around. You only need to change the data in the pivotItems on a page transition, not create more and more of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do this:

```
var newItem = new PivotItem { Header = "Added" };

MyPivot.Items.Add(newItem);
```

Beware of potential performance implications of having lots of times though.

Comment: I believe that all xaml design can be generated manually in .cs, I was just wondering
if there is easyiest way... (cloning, inflating, something like that)

Comment: @Janci is your question "is it possible?" OR "what are the options and how do they compare?"