# Referencing a dynamically created control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dynamic, controls

I know how to create a dynamic control in c#:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "This is a new textblock";
```

But how would I reference this newly created control through code?
I browsed the net for a solution, and came across this code:

```
TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)this.FindName("TB");
tb.Text = "Text property changed";
```

Every time I create a new control with a name I get an exception:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "This is a new textblock";
tb.Name = "TB";
```

> "The parameter is incorrect."

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 dynamic controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489818/wp7-dynamic-controls)

Comment: http://10rem.net/blog/2010/12/08/dynamically-generating-controls-in-wpf-and-silverlight

Comment: What is the class calling the assignment TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)this.FindName("TB");?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Exception "The parameter is incorrect." may be occurring because of the duplicate names of the controls created.

For the dynamic control part : you must be adding that control to some Grid or Stackpanel or something. you can reference that dynamic control by getting the content or children of the parent control.

Like :

```
TextBlock Tb= new TextBlock();
tb.Text = "Hello";

ContentPanel.Children.Add(Tb);
```

//to reference :

```
var content = ContentPanel.Children;
foreach(UIElement uiElem in content)
{
  if(uiElem.GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
  {
     TextBlock tb = uiElem as TextBlock;
     tb.Text = "Hyee";
  }
}
```

Hope, it might help.

(Note: I have written this code directly here and not copied from VS, so please check syntax and spellings.)

Comment: Thanks Joel.. Its my first answer which got selected

Comment: Clear and fantastic answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use reference dynamic controls this way.
But another way is that you can also keep a list of the references when you create the controls.