# How to find a child control from ToogleSwitch

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

How do i find a control placed inside a ToogleSwitch ContentTemplate in ToggleSwitch_Checked event?

I tried toogle.Switch.FindName("NameOftControlToFindHere") but it returns NULL.

Here is the XAMl markup, I am trying to find tbMonthlyLimitData textblock programtically in ToggleSwitch_Checked event.

```
<toolkit:ToggleSwitch Header="Monthly Limit" Margin="0,10,0,0" Name="tsMonthlyLimit" Checked="ToggleSwitch_Checked">
                        <toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="ts">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Name="tbMonthlyLimit"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Hello" Name="tbMonthlyLimitData"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </toolkit:ToggleSwitch.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: Have you tried using Blend for that?

Comment: May be this could help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460533/referencing-a-dynamically-created-control/11471602#11471602

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are facing is namescopes - the named its is within a different scope. One way to locate it is to use [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/)::

```
var textBlock = tsMonthlyLimit.Descendants()
                              .OfType<TextBlock>()
                              .Single(i => i.Name=="tbMonthlyLimitData");
```

Comment: 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ToggleSwitch' does not contain a definition for 'Descendants' and no extension method 'Descendants' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.ToggleSwitch' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)